# UTF-8 to UTF16 Parsing

Tags: java, xml, utf-8, xml-parsing, utf-16

I have an XML that is UTF-8 and have some special characters in Chinese, I need  to parse this xml.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
factory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
factory.setValidating(true);

//byte[] buffer = xmlMsg.getBytes("UTF-16");

logger.info("transformToUTP " + xmlMsg);


//byte[] buffer = soapMessage.getBytes();
//ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);               


InputSource is = new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(
                   xmlMsg.getBytes("UTF-16")));

Document doc = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(is);
//Document doc = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(
                   new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlMsg)));                              

XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
xpath.setNamespaceContext(getNameSpace());

XPathExpression soapBodyExpr = xpath.compile(BODY_XPATH_EXP);
Node soapBody = (Node) soapBodyExpr.evaluate(doc,
            XPathConstants.NODE);

Node reqMsgNode = soapBody.getFirstChild();
```

I am getting a null pointer exception on reqMsgNode.

Comment: why did you convert your xml into a String?  that was your first problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do not convert xml into a string, parse it as is, use

`DocummentBuilder.parse(File)` or `DocumentBuilder.parse(InputStream)`

the parser will take encoding from xml declaration e.g. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`, and if it is missing then it will use UTF-8 by default